# anjlab get product name and price from google play

Tags: android, android-billing

I'm using anjlab https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 for billing in my app.

I'm new on android studio and I'd like some help with my code.

```
bp.getPurchaseListingDetails("YOUR PRODUCT ID FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE");
```

As a result it will be a SkuDetails object with the following info included:

> public final String productId; public final String title; public final
>   String description; public final boolean isSubscription; public final
>   String currency; public final Double priceValue; public final String
>   priceText;

Ok, so I'd like to get, for example, product price, I'm trying:

```
    String price = bp.getPurchaseListingDetails("productidname").priceText;
    pricevalue.setText(price);
```

It is returning null. I'm doing something wrong??

Comment: This is not an Android Studio issue, don't use the Android Studio tag

Comment: having same issue

Answer (score 7):

I know it's been late, but below is my answer which will work for you.

Write below code in

```
public void onBillingInitialized() {
     SkuDetails sku = bp.getPurchaseListingDetails("YOUR PRODUCT ID FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE");
     String price =sku.priceText;
}
```

I am sure your problem will be resolved.